# record and run option in android robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am very new to android. How robotium framework has to be used ? Is there a record and playback option in that or should we manually write the test case. Please get me a tool for robotium which records and playsback quickly

Comment: why it got down voted ?

Comment: please go ahead and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MonkeyTalk](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk) it's free, open source and pretty easy to use.

Comment: link of MonkeyTalk appears to be not available now

Answer (score 2):

In Robotium, record and play back option is available. You can record the actions and re-run it. Scripts will be written automatically. For more details please refer following:

[Robotium Installation](http://robotium.com/pages/installation)

Answer (score 0):

In Robotium, you have to write your own test cases, but there is software out there that will let you record your test cases by clicking through your actual app.  It's called TestDroid:

http://bitbar.com/products

Comment: thanks. Is there any freeware for this ? just checked testdroid, it is not free :(

Comment: I don't believe that there is, or at least I haven't come across it yet and I've been looking.

Comment: MonkeyTalk is (as mentioned in the other comment).

Answer (score -1):

Robotium Recorder is an Eclipse plugin which does the same stuff you are looking for :

http://robotium.com/products/robotium-recorder